# Endless wave animation with paper.js and reactJS. TypeError: Cannot read property 'point' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paperjs

I'm trying to create an endlessly waving line (animation) the same way it's done here http://paperjs.org/tutorials/animation/creating-animations/

with paper.js & React JS.

But I get the error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'point' of undefined."

whenever I try to loop over the segments inside the path.

Funny thing is, that, If I don't loop, I don't get this error with 'point' property and everything works perfectly fine (I see the animation).

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './Canvas.css';
    import Paper, { Path, Point, onFrame } from "paper";
    
    
    const Wdivider = Math.round(window.innerWidth / 6);
    const linesNumber = Math.round(window.innerHeight / 10);
    const points = [[0, 0], [Wdivider, 25], [2*Wdivider, 0], [3*Wdivider, 25], [4*Wdivider, 0], [5*Wdivider, 25],[window.innerWidth, 0]];
    
    
    var topLeft = [0, window.innerHeight/2];
    var bottomRight = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight/2];
    
    
    let myPath;
    let copy;
    
    class Canvas extends React.Component{
    
    
        componentDidMount() {
            this.createLines();
            Paper.view.onFrame = event => {
                  this.onFrameAnim(event, myPath);
            };
        }
    
        createLines(){
            var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            Paper.setup(myCanvas);
    
                myPath = new Path({segments: points});
    
                myPath.smooth();
    
    
            }
    
            //Animation
    
            onFrameAnim(event, path) {
    
                
                for (let i=0; i < myPath.length; i++ ) {
                    if (myPath.segments[i].point.y >= 0) {
                        myPath.segments[i].point.y -= 50;
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        myPath.segments[i].point.y += 50;
                    }
                }
            
            }
    
    
        
        render(){
            return (
                <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true" /> 
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default Canvas;
```

Comment: Seems like you are passing a path into onFrameAnim function, but never use it. change myPath to path inside this function. Also, I think you should define the myPath and copy variables inside the class.

Comment: You're using `myPath.length;` in your `for` loop. Perhaps you mean `myPath.segments.length`.

Comment: szczocik thank you. It helped! The animation is different, but it least there is no error now. so I can proceed with what I've got =)

Comment: nicholaswmin I've tried replacing it with just a number even, still it won;t work =( But thanks a lot for your support and try